# Adding numbers in an object is not working as expected in JS

Tags: javascript, addition, parseint

I created an object with Int values and some functions in js as below

```
var obj = function (int1,int2,int3){
  this.int1=int1;
this.int2=int2;
this.int3=int3;
this.add= (function (){
return parseInt(int1)+parseInt(int2)+parseInt(int3)
}());
```

When I execute the code

```
var a= new obj(1,2,3);
console.log(a.add);
```

The Answer is

> NaN

Type of all the int1,int2.int3,add is Number.
**Whats the problem with My code & How to correct it**

Comment: Is the lack of parentheses in `console.log(a.add)` intended (`console.log(a.add)()`)? Furthermore, there is a lack of a closing bracket for the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var obj = function(int1, int2, int3) {
    this.int1 = int1;
    this.int2 = int2;
    this.int3 = int3;
    this.add = function() {
        return parseInt(int1) + parseInt(int2) + parseInt(int3)
    }};
```

And, Call above as:

```
var a = new obj(1, 2, 3);
console.log(a.add());
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful, you should explain why the OP has their issue and how to fix it, then show some code. What happens when the OP does `a.int1 = 10; a.add()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a instance of the function with [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator and you could skip `parseInt`, which works better with a given base.

```js
var Obj = function (int1, int2, int3) {
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
        this.int3 = int3;
        this.add = function () {
            return this.int1 + this.int2 + this.int3;
        }
    },
    instance = new Obj(1, 2, 3);

console.log(instance.add());
```

Comment: You don't need to use *this* as the variables in the *add* function have a closure to the variables in the execution context of the constructor that created the instance. Until the OP does `Obj.int1 = 6` of course. ;-)

Comment: right, but if op want public properties, then `this` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

run this code:

```
var obj = function (int1, int2, int3) {
    this.int1 = int1;
    this.int2 = int2;
    this.int3 = int3;
    this.add = (function () {
        return parseInt(int1) + parseInt(int2) + parseInt(int3)
    } ())
};

var a = new obj(1,2,3);
console.log(a.add);  // 6
```

your code lost a `}`

Comment: you also can do this like `this.add = parseInt(int1) + parseInt(int2) + parseInt(int3);`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it's working fine :**

```
var obj = function (int1,int2,int3){
  this.int1=int1;
this.int2=int2;
this.int3=int3;
this.add= (function (){
return parseInt(int1)+parseInt(int2)+parseInt(int3)
}())
}

var a= new obj(1,2,3);
console.log(a.add); // 6
```

**Working fiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/90ku8qae/

**Update :**

You forgot to add the closing bracket for the function `obj`. I just added and everything is working fine now.